# How to print .txt file containing esc/pos commands using command prompt in windows?

Tags: windows, printing, command, escpos

I am trying to print ESC/pos commands from the .txt file using windows command prompt.

Let me explain what I tried so far:

I have connected my Epson Tm-m30 printer. Using a virtual port driver I can print the .txt file using the following command:

```
print /d:COM1 'file path'
```

**Now my question:** as it is, ESC/pos printer needs to print the ESC/pos commands like a paper cut, barcode printing, etc. When I paste the ESC/pos commands in the .txt file, it is print as it is, not as ESC/pos commands.

I am trying to print The following ESC/pos commands:

```
\x1B\x40
\x1D(k\x0d\x00\x30\x50\x30TEST PRINT
\x1D(k\x03\x00\x30\x51\x
```

But while printing it is printing it looks like above, not as ESC commands.

How do I print ESC/pos commands using a .txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no commands built into Windows by default, so the following options are possible.

- Use the tools distributed by EPSON
  [Send Data Tool](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5027&scat=47&pcat=52)
  [Issuing Receipts with Barcodes](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=270)
- Use a free tool published by someone somewhere
- Create your own with a script tool such as PowerShell
  [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.1)
- Make your own with C++/C#/VB etc.
  [Regex.Unescape(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?view=net-5.0)
  [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)
- Create a file with binary data instead of text and copy it to COM1 with the `copy /b` command

Comment: First thanks for the response kunif am using dart programming language in that I have converted the text to binary as I said and used copy /d  'file path' COM1 but no luck still printing that binary character my binary character is : 0001101101000000010100100110010101100111011101010110110001100001011100100011101000100000011000010100000100100  like this binary am writing in my text file but couldn't get esc pos printer type format

Comment: Why don't you create similar data with EPSON tools and compare whether the data is correct? By the way, it seems to be a typo, but `copy /d` is an decryption, not a binary copy.

Comment: soryy i have used copy /b only it was a typo

Comment: EPSON tool solution got worked thanks for guiding @kunif epson send data tool works for me